# On the inequality $\vert u'(t)\vert \leq ct^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, analyticity

Suppose we have **real** function
$$
\vert u'(t)\vert \leq ct^{-1}
$$
where $c$ is a constant, and $t\in(0,\infty)$. Shall we have some properties of the function $u(t)$? More precisely, can we infer the range of $u(t)$?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking real functions, we could have $u (t)=\log t $ (with range $\mathbb R $), or $u (t)=c $, with range a single point.